# I would like to read content of txt file ends it with ( ; ) semi-colon character

Tags: powershell-2.0, powershell-4.0

I have `txt` file that has 50 long character in LINE1 but, I only want to read the first 10 sometimes 11 or even less character and end on semi-colon.

basically, I want to get the characters before the semi-colon.

**First.txt**
`1234567891;45416564653afsd`

**Second.txt**
`124562;455466asdfa`

Appreciate anyone's help..

Comment: You seem to have mistaken us for a code writing service. We're glad to help, but we expect you to make an effort to solve the problem yourself first. When you've done so and run into a problem, you can come back, explain the problem you've encountered, post the *relevant portions* of your code, and ask a specific question, and we'll try to assist. Good luck.

Comment: You'll stand a much better chance of getting answers if you put more effort into your questions. Well-crafted questions not only benefit you, but future readers as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following returns the portion of each line from input file `File` before the first `;`.
If there is no `;` the entire line is returned.

```
Get-Content File | ForEach-Object { ($PSItem -split ';')[0] }
```

To give you a sense of the elasticity of PowerShell, you can rewrite the following to this much more terse form, utilizing built-in aliases (though it's better to be verbose and avoid aliases in *scripts*):

```
gc File | % { ($_ -split ';')[0] }
```

Answer (score -2):

In python:

```
file = open('input.txt', 'r')
while True:
    c = file.read(1)
    if c == ';':
        break
    # Ensure loop break at EOL
    if not c:
        break
    print("Character: " + c)
```

Comment: This question is tagged PowerShell. What does Python have to do with anything? We don't answer questions here by posting code in random languages.